# linear operator norm on a neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

Say we have $\phi=(\phi_1\ldots \phi_n) \in C^1(D)$, where $D\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set.

Given that $d\phi({\bf 0})={\bf 0}$ (the null map) and that $\phi({\bf 0})={\bf 0 }$, why can we say that $\exists \ U$ a neighbourhood of ${\bf 0}$  such that  $\left \| d\phi_k(t) \right \|\le \frac{1}{2n}, \forall t\in U,k=1\ldots n?$
Are both informations required?
Thank you

Comment: I understand that $\left \| T \right \|\:=sup \frac{\left \| T(x) \right \|}{\left \| x \right \|}$, but I do not see how it follows from here. Can you explain it a bit more, please? Thank you.

Comment: Misread, please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: I think I got it though. If $d\phi({\bf 0})= {\bf 0}$ which is the null transformation, it means that the partial derivaties are null in the origin. So it means,by continuity of partial derivatives, that we can find an open set $U$ around ${\bf 0}$ such that $\frac{\partial \phi_k}{\partial x_i}$ < \epsilon$. Then we can make the norm  as small as we want, as the compoenents (partial derivatives) are as small as we want

Comment: $\phi$ is differentiable and its derivative is continuous and zero at (0,0,...,0), so each of $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n$ must have continuous derivative which is zero at 0.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you properly, by continuous derivative you mean a vector function that is cotninuous, right?

Answer (score 1):

Of your assumptions, only continuity of $d\phi$ and $d\phi(0)=0$ are required for such a neighborhood to exist.

$d\phi=[\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x_1},\dots,\frac{\partial \phi_n}{\partial x_n}]$ is continuous and 0 at 0 so $\phi_i'$ is too, so you can choose $\delta_i$ so that $|\phi_i'(x)|<1/(2n)$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$ for $x$ in some neighborhood of $0$. The intersection of each of those neighborhoods' embeddings in $\mathbb{R}^n$ will do what you want, i.e. $\{(x_1,\dots,x_n): x_i< \delta_i,\ i=1,\dots,n\}$.